# Bash script to replace all occurrences of string in files, including filenames

Tags: regex, perl, bash, unix, sh

I want to be able to replace the occurrences of one string with another in the file contents and filenames of all files within a directory minus the ".git" directory. I have the following code, which is good for changing the filenames but doesn't replace strings inside the files. What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash

# Replace occurances in files, lowercase
lower1=$(echo $1 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
lower2=$(echo $2 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
echo "Replacing $lower1 with $lower2..."
find . -type f \! -iregex '.\|./.git' -exec perl -i -pe 's/$lower1/$lower2/g' {} \;

# Replace all other occurances in files to capitalised
upper2=$(echo ${2:0:1} | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')${2:1}
echo "Replacing all $1 with $upper2..."
find . -type f \! -iregex '.\|./.git' -exec perl -i -pe 's/$1/$upper2/gi' {} \;

# Replace filenames. Use "bash -c" to pass files as arguments to mv command.
# This worked
find . -name "*$lower1*" -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1/$2/$3}"' -- {} $lower1 $lower2 \;
```

I did try sed, but that wasn't allowing case insensitivity.

I am testing this on OSX Mountain Lion if that makes a difference, though I do want this to work on Linux as well. I'm away from my Linux machine at the moment.

Comment: `sed` *does* do case-insensitivity with the `/i` flag.

Comment: Not on OSX apparently. The i flag is not portable.

Comment: Here the shell variables will not be interpolated due to the single quotes: `'s/$lower1/$lower2/g'`

Comment: Yes thanks bobbogo. I'm testing it with double quotes now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`File::Find`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html)

The following code will edit an entire directory tree, so I'd be careful how I used it.  Perhaps some testing first? :)

This script accepts two strings as arguments, and then replaces all occurances of $string1 with $string2.  For perfect lowercase matches, it will replace with a lowercase $string2, but for all other matches it will replace with uppercase $string2.

Currently, it will just do lowercase for file renames.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use File::Find;

die "Usage: $0 From_string To_string\n" if @ARGV != 2;

my ($from, $to) = map lc, @ARGV;

finddepth(sub {
    return if $File::Find::dir =~ /.git\b/;

    # Inplace Edit of files
    if (-f) {
        local @ARGV = $_;
        local $^I = '.bak';
        while (<>) {
            s/\Q$from/$to/g;
            s/\Q$from/\U$to/ig;
            print; 
        }
        #unlink "$_$^I";  # Uncomment if you want to delete backups
    }

    # Rename File
    my $newfile = $_;
    if ($newfile =~ s/\Q$from/$to/ig) {
        rename $_, $newfile;
    }
}, '.');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't know much about Perl so I would have to take a greater look into it, though it does seem your solution is not exactly what I want. I want to replace lowercase original strings with lowercase new strings and all other original strings with capitalised new strings.

Comment: I might be able to figure out how to do my own perl script, though I don't think it would be hard to determine the problem with my bash script.

Comment: Yes, it's still not at all clear to me what you're trying to replace.  If you gave some before and after examples, I might be able to better understand your goal.  Regardless, the method I proposed will work for changing all file contents and file names in a directory tree, while skipping the .git directories.

Comment: Although, reading your script again, I'm getting a better understanding.  One sec, might propose something in a moment.

Comment: Made an update to my solution to take into account my new understanding of your goal.

Comment: OK thanks, though I've found the problem with the bash script, so I will post that when I've tested it.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name .git -prune -o type f -exec perl -i -pe "s/\Q$1\E/\L$2\E/i" {} +
find . -name .git -prune -o type f -name "*$lower1*" -exec mmv "*$lower1*" "#1$lower2#2" {} +
```

If you are doing a lot of file renames, you should check for accidental removal of intermediate results. `mmv` does this admirably.

`+` is a useful performance boost for `find`.

Comment: Thanks, the performance definitely improves with +. But mmv doesn't take arguments after the from and to arguments.

Comment: I've tried using ; with mmv which is supposed to match all subdirectories but it doesn't seem to work: `mmv ";*$lower1*" "#1$lower2#2"` or `mmv ";$lower1*" "#1$lower2#2"`

Comment: Ah, mmv doesn't work on directories? I need it to work on directories too.

Comment: @matthew `mmv -r` to rename folders

Comment: @matthew When you use the `;` wildcard, don't forget that uses up one of the slots. `mmv ";*$lower1*" "#1#2$lower2#3"`

Comment: @matthew _mmv_ also lower-cases for you. `mmv ';*' '#1#l2'` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I managed to come up with. Thanks to all that helped me come to it:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Replace occurances in files, lowercase
lower1=$(echo $1 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
lower2=$(echo $2 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
echo "Replacing $lower1 with $lower2..."
find . -type f \! -iregex '.\|./.git' -exec perl -i'' -pe "s/$lower1/$lower2/g" {} +

# Replace all other occurances in files to capitalised
upper2=$(echo ${2:0:1} | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')${2:1}
echo "Replacing all $1 with $upper2..."
find . -type f \! -iregex '.\|./.git' -exec perl -i'' -pe "s/$1/$upper2/gi" {} +

# Replace filenames.
mmv -r ";*$lower1*" "#2$lower2#3"
```