# Perl script just deletes the contents of my files

Tags: regex, perl

I'm new to Perl so please forgive me. What I'm trying to do is use the execution of some external programs to convert a matched string into a substituted string. I've tried using this and it works, except that the substitution string contains a newline after it which I do not want:

```
perl -i'' -e '$from = "C"; $to = "00"; $match = "(" . $from . "[23456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz]{27,35})";' -pe 's/$match/`base58ChecksumEncode "$to\$(base58Converter -d $1 | cut -c 3- | rev | cut -c 9- |     rev | cut -c 3-)"`/eg;' file1.txt
```

But when I try to convert this to a script which works for all files recursively from the pwd, all contents of the files are removed. I cannot figure out why. Here is the content of the script I put together.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use File::Find;

die "Usage: $0 From_Character_Prefix To_Hex_Prefix\n" if @ARGV != 2;

my ($from, $to) = @ARGV;

$ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH}='/usr/local/lib';

finddepth(sub {
    return if $File::Find::dir =~ /.git\b/;

    if (-f) {
        local @ARGV = $_;
        local $^I = '.bak';
        while (<>) {
        my $match = "(" . $from . "[23456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz]{27,35})";
        s/$match/`base58ChecksumEncode "$to\$(base58Converter -d $1 | cut -c 3- | rev | cut -c 9- | rev | cut -c 3-)"`/eg;
        }
    }

}, '.');
```

Comment: Never use the naked `-i` switch until you have tested your code.

Comment: You  need to print ; inside your while(<>)

Comment: `[23456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz]` is better written `[2-9A-Za-z]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever using perl's in-place replacement, `$^I`, don't forget to actually `print` the line:

```
local @ARGV = $_;
local $^I = '.bak';
while (<>) {
   my $match = "(" . $from . "[23456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz]{27,35})";
   s/$match/`base58ChecksumEncode "$to\$(base58Converter -d $1 | cut -c 3- | rev | cut -c 9- | rev | cut -c 3-)"`/eg;
   print; # <--- Need this
}
```

Also, your regex could be simplified greatly using a range inside the character class: `[2-9A-Za-z]{27,35}`

**Update to remove the newline from the `` return value**

```
while (<>) {
    my $match = "(" . $from . "[23456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz]{27,35})";
    s{$match}{
        my $command = `base58ChecksumEncode "$to\$(base58Converter -d $1 | cut -c 3- | rev | cut -c 9- | rev | cut -c 3-)"`;
        chomp $command;
        $command;
    }eg;
    print;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I based my script from the script you gave me the other day: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22991103/bash-script-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-string-in-files-including-filenames but your script did not contain the print. Was that your mistake or is it something I do not understand?

Comment: Also the character class contains missing characters. It was easy for me to copy and paste the list.

Comment: And yes, I forgot to include that `print`.  I was actually searching for that post when you just responded.  Have corrected the it.

Comment: And yeah, given there are missing characters in that range, perhaps leaving it alone is the way to go.  If you wanted it shorter, this would work though: `[2-9A-HJ-NP-Za-km-z]{27,35}`

Comment: Works almost great. There is just one other thing, which is the new-line added to the substitution. Maybe I can figure out a way...

Comment: Adding `| xargs echo -n` works to remove the newline.

Comment: can also remove the newline using `chomp`.  I'm kinda of curious what everything in the backticks is trying to do, as I suspect there's a perlish way to accomplish it.  But if you're getting the results you want, fine as is.